# Linking against static system library without full path in CMake

Tags: cmake, static-linking

When building a CMake find module for a common system library, `libatomic`, I have noticed that if one creates a `STATIC IMPORTED` target with the name of a static library (i.e. `libatomic.a`) and then add it to the `LINK_LIBRARIES` of a non-imported target (e.g. `foo`) the behaviour is not as expected. For example by:

```
add_library(Atomic::atomic STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Atomic::atomic
    PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "libatomic.a"
)

add_executable(foo)
target_link_libraries(foo
    PRIVATE
        Atomic::atomic
)
```

The behaviour that I would expect would be that something like the following would be added to the link line on Linux:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -latomic -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Or:

```
-l:libatomic.a
```

However, what I actually see, when using the `Unix Makefiles` generator, is that `libatomic.a` is added as a dependency of `foo` in the Makefile. Moreover just `libatomic.a` is added to link line instead of one of the desired forms. Is there a way that I can achieve what I am aiming for without having to find the full path of my target library, e.g. `libatomic.a`?

The rationale for this is that it is somewhat non-trivial to find the path of `libatomic.a` as it may be in some compiler-specific location (for example in the devtoolset location).

Comment: "The rationale for this is that it is somewhat non-trivial to find the path of `libatomic.a` as it may be in some compiler-specific location (for example in the devtoolset location)." - It is responsibility of the *toolchain* to tell CMake where system libraries are located. So `find_library` should work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev This doesn't appear to actually work though - for example if I try `find_library(Atomic_LIBRARY NAMES libatomic.a)` it will not find the library despite using a GCC from a devtoolset which has `libatomic.a` installed within it. Is there something else that I should be doing?

Comment: Probably, your toolchain is not quite correct, as it doesn't provide the paths to the compiler's includes.